# How to get output of Python Selenium code in Excel format?

Tags: python, excel

```
import urllib2    
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = ("http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/CA")    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
driver.get(url)

driver

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding0"]')

for e in elements:    
    print e.text    
url = driver.current_url    
company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="jcn"]').text

contact_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="contact_info"]').text    
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="adress_info"]').text    
address_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="address-info adinfoex"]').text

estd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="fr"]').text    
ratings = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="last"]').text

tf = 'textfile.csv'    
f2 = open(tf, 'a+')

f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [company_name]]) + ',')    
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [contact_number]]) + ',')    
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [address]]) + ',')    
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [address_info]]) + ',')    
f2.write(', '.join([data.encode('utf-8') for data in [estd_ratings]]) + '\n')

f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started. The important thing is to ensure your xpath entries select exactly what you need. Python's [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) can be used to convert the lists obtained automatically into comma separated entries without you needing to add your own commas:

```
import csv
import urllib2    
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]


url = ("http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/CA")    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
driver.get(url)

search_entries = [
    ("CompanyName",     "//span[@class='jcn']"),
    ("ContactNumber",   "//p[@class='contact-info']/span/a"),
    ("Address",         "//span[@class='desk-add jaddt']"),
    ("AddressInfo",     "//p[@class='address-info adinfoex']"),
    ("Estd",            "//li[@class='fr']"),
    ("Ratings",         "//li[@class='last']/a/span[@class='rt_count']")]

with open('textfile.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Write header
    csv_output.writerow([name for name, xpath in search_entries])
    entries = []

    for name, xpath in search_entries:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))

    csv_output.writerows(zip(*entries))
```

Which would give you a CSV file looking something like:

```
CompanyName,ContactNumber,Address,AddressInfo,Estd,Ratings
Bansal Investment & Consult...,+(91)-22-38578062,Manpada-thane West.. | more..,"CA, Tax Consultants,  more...",Estd.in 2003,27 Ratings
G.Kedia & Associates,+(91)-22-38555914,"Station Road, Thane We.. | more..","CA, Company Registration Consultants,  more...",Estd.in 2010,17 Ratings
Tarun Shah & Associates,+(91)-22-38552775,"Mogra Lane, Andheri Ea.. | more..","CA, Income Tax Consultants,  more...",Estd.in 2000,12 Ratings
Hemant Shah And Associates LLP,+(91)-22-38588696,"Azad Road, Andheri Eas.. | more..","CA, Company Secretary,  more...",Estd.in 1988,65 Ratings
```

The loop requests each of your xpath searches and creates an array entries for each search. Each search returns an array of matches so you end up with an array of arrays of entries.

This needs to then be written to a CSV file. `entries` is in column order, and the CSV file needs to be written in row order. To do this `zip(*entries)` is used to convert to row order. As the whole array is now in the correct order, a single call to `writerows` can be used to write the whole file in one go.

The additional benefit of using Python's CSV library is that if any of the fields contain commas, it will automatically add quotes around the field to ensure Excel does not read interpret it as another column. Note, you will probably need to change the default cell type formatting when it is loaded as Excel will try and guess.